# How to flag single value in my array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have `array` of `arrays` in `js` and want to color rows which are different, so I add for every element array new value 'color' and set `background-color` of my `tr` to this value:

```
  for (var element in res.data.results) {
    if(res.data.results[element]['name'] === nextProps.name){
      res.data.results[element].color = 'white';
      tmpResult.push(res.data.results[element]);
    }
  }

  for (var value in valuesToCheck) {
    for (var i = 0; i < (tmpResult.length - 1); i++) {
        if(tmpResult[i][valuesToCheck[value]] === tmpResult[i+1][valuesToCheck[value]]){
          continue;
        } else {
          tmpResult[i].color = '#DC143C';
          tmpResult[i+1].color = '#DC143C';
        }
    }
  }

    <tbody>
      {this.state.results.map(result =>
        <tr style={{'backgroundColor': result.color}}>
          <td>{result.name}</td>
        </tr>
      )}
    </tbody>
```

I have many of values in my element(element is an array in my result which is my main object I take values to table from) and now I want to color not all the row, but only values which changed. How can I do this? I tried to make a map in my array where value become a key and value of that key will be 'color' and then to change background in my `th` for single cell:

```
res.data.results[elem]['name'].color = 'white';
```

, but i got an error:

```
TypeError: can't assign to properties of (new String("my name as string")): not an object
```

Comment: On which line this error `this is not an object` occurred ?

Comment: Could you provide some valid test data for `res.data.results` and `valuesToCheck`? Adding `console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data.results, null ,1))`  should give you easily copy-paste:able output in the console.

Comment: Error occurreted when i trying to do `res.data.results[element]['name'].color = 'white';`

Comment: `{ "name": "name_val",  "uuid": "uuid_val", "varsion": "version_val"  }`, just regular values, standart json.

Comment: convert `res.data.results[element].*` to `element.*` since you already have the element and not the index of the element in `res.data.results`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just made an `array` from every value in my element:

```
    for (var elem in res.data.results) {
      if(res.data.results[elem]['name'].toLowerCase() === nextProps.name){
        res.data.results[elem]['name'] = [res.data.results[elem]['name'], 'black'];
        res.data.results[elem]['another_parameter'] = [res.data.results[elem]['another_parameter'], 'black'];
        tmpResult.push(res.data.results[elem]);
      }
```

Then I changed it for another color if I need to:

```
    for (var value in valuesToCheck) {
      for (var i = 0; i < (tmpResult.length - 1); i++) {
          if(tmpResult[i][valuesToCheck[value]][0] === tmpResult[i+1][valuesToCheck[value]][0]){
            continue;
          } else {
            tmpResult[i][valuesToCheck[value]][1] = 'red';
            tmpResult[i+1][valuesToCheck[value]][1] = 'red';
          }
      }
    }
```

And add it to my `table` in `html` code:

```
    <tbody>
      {this.state.results.map(result =>
        <tr>
          <td style={{'color': result['name'][1]}}>{result.name[0]}</td>
          <td style={{'color': result['another_value'][1]}}>{result.another_value[0]}</td>
        </tr>
      )}
    </tbody>
```

I think exist better solution, so I keep waiting for responses.